# Render form in eZ Publish 5

Tags: ezpublish

I have a small issue with rendering a form. Specifically I am rendering a form   but I can't get its description value. I am rendering my form this way:

```
    {{ form_start( form ) }}    
    {{ form_errors( form ) }}
     {% for form_child_key, form_child in form.children %}
         This is label;         {{ form_child.vars.label }}
         and here i whant to render description like this:
         {{ form_child.vars.description }} but this is not working
     {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Symfony question, not necessarily an eZ Publish one. eZ uses Symfony to power its kernel. In instances like this, you should be looking at the [Symfony form docs](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/twig_reference.html).

It looks like you are using your form start/end tags correctly, you are just missing the form children calls. Try this:

```
{{ form_start( form ) }}    
    {{ form_errors( form ) }}
    {% for form_child in form.children %}
        {{ form_row(form_child) }}

        {* you can also call parts directly: *}

        {{ form_label(form_child) }}
        {{ form_widget(form_child) }}
        {{ form_errors(form_child) }}
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```